# How to remove Windows 10 dual bootloader but still be able to use the other non-default windows?

Tags: windows, bootloader, dualboot

I have two windows 10s currently installed on my PC. Whenever my PC boots up, it shows that dual bootloader showing the two windows I installed. But I mainly boot into Windows(1, previously installed windows). I have set Windows(1) as the default but still I get that prompt. I have seen some articles that I have to delete one of the os, either Windows(1), or Windows(2, newly installed Windows) to remove the bootloader but Windows(2) is important for me.

So what can I do to remove the dual bootloader without deleting or damaging any of the two Windows?
Btw I can't open Windows(1) because its my father's.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. On the one hand, you want to remove one entry from the bootloader which would result in only one bootable Windows (your father's). On the other hand you write that the second installation is important to you. But if you remove it from the bootloader you won't have access to it. So what is your goal? To remove an entry from the bootloader you could use EasyBCD, but be careful and maybe practice on a test system or so to prevent any damage if you are not familiar with these tools.

Comment: This ^^^. The only remark/correction is to use EasyUEFI, not EasyBCD which is exclusively for old BIOS systems.

Comment: Hi, I am the the author of the question. What I want exactly is that both the Windows should have their separate bootloaders, they should not be contained in a single 'Windows Boot Manager', which obviously results in windows dual bootloader.